# The time convergence of stochastic integral and Doob's convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, martingales, weak-convergence

Consider the process $$X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}dW_{s},$$ where $e^{-s}$ is deterministic.

I am wondering if $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_{t}$ exists almost surely... I understand that $X_{t}$ in the case is a martingale, so we can use Doob's martingale convergence theorem. However, I have no idea about how to show $$\sup_{t}\mathbb{E}X_{t}^{-}<\infty.$$ If we can show this, then yes, $X_{t}$ converges almost surely to a limit..

Also, is there any way to know the distribution of the limit? I know that the distribution converges since it converges almost surely, but I am not sure how to compute the limiting distribution.. using central limit theorem??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E|X_t|^{2}=\int_0^{t} e^{-2s} ds=\frac  1  2(1-e^{-t}) <1$ for all $t$ and this implies $E|X_t|$ is bounded.

The limiting distribution is $N(0,\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2s} ds)$ i.e. $N(0, \frac 1 2)  $.

Comment: Convergence is mean square implies convergence in distribution. Our variables are jointly normal. The limiting distribution is just obtained by writing the variance of $X_t$ and taking limit as $t \to \infty$. @cherrycakeloe

Comment: Using characteristic functions is is easy to see that limit of normal variables in distribution is always normal (or degenerate).  @cherrycakeloe

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the distribution: It [holds](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/distribution-of-stochastic-integral) $$\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}\sim N(0,\int_{0}^{t}|f(\tau)|^{2}d\tau),$$ since $f(t)=e^{-t}$ is a square integrable deterministic function. As you now know the distribution of $X_t$ and it converges in distribution to $X_\infty$ you can calculate its distribution.

Comment: As $X_t$ converges a.s. it also conveges in distribution. So you just have to calculate the integrtal $\int_0^\infty e^{-2s} ds$.